# В "table" обнаружен начальный тег "form"

Tags: html, вёрстка

У меня есть таблица, в которую я вывожу данные из БД, но когда я вывел их, я посмотрел через Mozilla FireFox исходный код, и нашёл ошибку, скажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

[image: Скриншот]

Вот какую ошибку пишет мозилла когда подводишь курсор и красному:

> В "table" обнаружен начальный тег "form"

Я проверил весь код, нигде больше тегов form нету. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: А как Вы выводите данные из БД?

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_company WHERE active = '1'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
 while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $id = $res["id"];

  echo "
  
   <tr style = \"text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid black;\" class = \"td_link\">
   <form action = \"buy.php\" method = \"post\" name = \"buy_form\">
    <input type = \"hidden\" name = \"id\" value = \"$id\">
    <td>" .$res["name"] ."</td>
    <td>" .$res["price"] ."</td>
    <td>" .$res["percent"] ."</td>
    <td>" .$res["summ"] ."</td>
    </form>
   </tr>
  ";
 }
}

Comment: @Csharp, Разместите всю форму в одном <td> и пройдете валидацию

Answer (score 2):

А не пробовали таблицу обернуть в FORM?

Т.е.

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr><td><input></input></td></tr>
        ....
   </table>
</form>
```

Это во-первых,

а во-вторых - у вас идет `<tr><form><td>`, может быть стоит попробовать `<tr><td><form>`?

Comment: Для ТС обернуть всю таблицу в форму не пойдет, т.к. ему, при такой структуре, надо отправлять только два значения: **id** и **count**, вот разместить формы в один <td> - решение правильное.

Comment: Ну это зависит от целей, если правка только по одной записи - тогда нет смысла все в форму оборачивать, а вот если необходимо несколько записей править - тогда самое оно.

И поменять чуть-чуть для этого - вместо `name = "id"` писать `name = "id[]"` и т.д.

И "ой"... Мне показалось, что это форма для правки записей, а она для покупки. Тогда - да, в одну форму не стоит.

Comment: Хотя почему не стоит?

Можно же вместо кнопок сделать чекбокс напротив каждого товара.

Можно будет покупать не поштучно, а сразу пачками. Удобнее намного.

Хотя опять же - а если цели такой нет?.. Может тогда поставить ее (цель)?))